# How do you replace 'Y' from input with YES?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way how to replace an input text/letter with printed statement in python? I've tried the("", end"r") but it doesn't work.

I'd like the y/Y which users type in to be replaced with YES and the same with n/N - replaced with NO.

```
user_choice = input("Are you ready to play? (Y/N)\n---\n").upper()
    while user_choice:
        if user_choice == "Y":
            print("YES", end="\r")
            get_random_word()
            break
        elif user_choice == "N":
            print('NO', end="\r")
```

Comment: What terminal are you using? Does it support overwriting lines with carriage returns/backspaces? If not, there isn't anything Python can do about it.

Comment: why don't you use replace method to change the user_choice value?

Comment: You might capture a single char, check if that's `Y` or `N` (without the user hitting Return) and then print `ES` or `O` afterwards or something like that. Anyway, that's probably _way_ to much effort for very little effect.

Comment: @Brian currently just using github and repl.it and deploying to heroku so I think carriage return should work

Comment: @saeedhosseini I tried that but it doesn't erase the 'y' or 'n' which is entered by user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by taking the cursor up one line up (where Y or N was typed) and then deleting the line. Then replacing it with YES or No

This can be done by using a function, shown in the code below.

```
import sys

def delete_last_line():
    "Use this function to delete the last line in the STDOUT"

    #cursor up one line
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A')

    #delete last line
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[2K')

user_choice = input("Are you ready to play? (Y/N)\n---\n").upper()
while user_choice:
    if user_choice == "Y":
        delete_last_line()
        print("YES")
        get_random_word()
        break
    elif user_choice == "N":
        delete_last_line()
        print('NO')
```